# How to get array of objects from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, json, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following json in my realtime database:

```
{
  "stickers": {
    "StickerPack0": {
      "Sticker0": {
        "image": "https://imgur.com/SKz7cOw.png"
      },
      "Sticker1": {
        "image": "https://imgur.com/SKz7cOw.png"
      },
      "Sticker2": {
        "image": "https://imgur.com/SKz7cOw.png"
      },
      "Sticker3": {
        "image": "https://imgur.com/SKz7cOw.png"
      },
      "Sticker4": {
        "image": "https://imgur.com/SKz7cOw.png"
      },
      "price": 0.99,
      "title": "Happy Hamster"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are `price`, `title` and array of 5 objects (`Sticker0`, `Sticker1`, ...).

To parse it I created the following entity:

```
data class StickerPack(
    var title: String? = null,
    var price: Double? = null,
    var stickers: List<String>? = null
)
```

Here's the way how I parse it:

```
query = database.child("stickers")
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Timber.e(error.toException())
                view?.onStickerListFailed()
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    val stickersFirebase = snapshot.children

                    stickersFirebase.forEach { data ->
                        val sticker = data.getValue(StickerPack::class.java)
                        stickers.add(sticker!!)
                    }

                    view?.onStickerListLoaded(stickers)
                }
            }
        })
```

But in this situation I can get only such fields as `title` and `price` and can't understand how can I transform `Sticker` objects to array of strings. So, how can I find the solution of this problem? I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stickers are not array. So you can't get it as array. You can use HashMap instead. Or change the structure of JSON

Comment: @PankajKumar, yes, it's not an array, but as I understand, there's no way to keep arrays in firebase realtime database

Comment: ahh got it. So you need to go with HashMap implementation instead of StickerPack. You will require few handling to identify wether value of a key (in hasmap) is String, Long or Object. In case of object, you can parse it to image-urls and prepare an array